# Image URL is invalid message for ImageResponseCard in AWS Lex

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lex

I tried to configure multiple images in the Lambda I use for my Lex ChatBot and got an "Image URL is invalid" message.

[image: Here is how it looks in the test]

This is how the configuration in the lambda looks like:

```
        "imageResponseCard": {
                "title": my title",
                "imageUrl": "https://my/imgae.png",
                "buttons": [{"text": "button1", "value": "button1"}, 
                            {"text": "button2", "value": "button2"}],
        }
```

Comment: Ensure that your image URL is publicly accessible and that the URL length does not exceed 250 characters.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lexv2/latest/dg/API_ImageResponseCard.html

Comment: I already checked it. This is not the source of the problem

Comment: I think the image might need to be hosted on s3 to be valid